# Gridview empty rows when exporting CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview that I'm trying to export to a csv file, but I'm not getting any rows just column names.

```
 <div style ="height:600px; width:auto; overflow:auto;">
        <p class="padding">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewBICARB" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                Caption="Bicarb Operator Checks" 
                CaptionAlign="Top"
                EmptyDataText="Data Not Available" 
                Width="100%" 
                AllowPaging="false" 
                AllowSorting="true" 
                ShowHeader="true" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField  DataField="FeedCheck" HeaderText="FeedCheck" />
                    <asp:BoundField  DataField="VisualCheck" HeaderText="VisualCheck" />
                </Columns>
                <RowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </p>
</div>
```

This is my C#

```
protected void btnExportReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

            GridViewBICARB.AllowSorting = false;
            GridViewBICARB.AllowPaging = false;
            GridViewBICARB.DataBind();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = 0; k < GridViewBICARB.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                //add separator
                sb.Append(GridViewBICARB.Columns[k].HeaderText + ',');
            }
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < GridViewBICARB.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < GridViewBICARB.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    //add separator
                    sb.Append(GridViewBICARB.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text + ',');
                }
                //append new line
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }
            Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
```

My output is just the column names.

> FeedCheck,VisualCheck,

I've tried removing the following as suggested in another question.

> GridViewBICARB.AllowPaging = false;
>   GridViewBICARB.DataBind();

But no help....

Comment: Why are you exporting the GridView and not the source data?

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how to export from the source? @VDWWD

Comment: The same source you set for the GridView you can use for the export. But it is better to use a specialized library for exporting like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @VDWWD Anyway to do just off the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding `OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging"`to my gridview. The PageIndexChanging event is raised when one of the pager buttons is clicked, but before the GridView control handles the paging operation. This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a routine.

In my case this was my routine...

```
protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewBICARB.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridViewBICARB.DataBind();
}
```

The NewPageIndex property was to determine the index of the page selected by the user in the page selection element of the DataGrid control. This value is often used to set the CurrentPageIndex property of the DataGrid control to display the selected page.

Then I removed the following...

```
    GridViewBICARB.AllowSorting = false;
    GridViewBICARB.AllowPaging = false;
    GridViewBICARB.DataBind();
```

And wallah it works!